# Mongo db query with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mongodb

Attempting to query a mongo db using `mongodb-odm 2.x` and `PHP`. Here's some comparisons:-

```
#1
$results = $dm->createQueryBuilder(self::$repository)
    ->find()
    ->field('isAdmin')->equals(true)
    ->field('language')->equals($this->getCountry()->getRegion())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

**returns:**

```
 ["items":"Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Iterator\CachingIterator":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["iterator":"Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Iterator\CachingIterator":private]=>
  object(Generator)#566 (0) {
  }
  ["iteratorAdvanced":"Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Iterator\CachingIterator":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["iteratorExhausted":"Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Iterator\CachingIterator":private]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

```
#2
$results = $dm->getRepository(self::$repository)->findBy([
   'isAdmin' => true,
   'language' => $this->getCountry()->getRegion()
]);
```

**returns:**

```
array(0) { }
```

```
#3
$results = $dm->getRepository(self::$repository)->findBy([
    'isAdmin' => true
]);
```

**returns:**

```
array(182) {
  [0]=>
  object(Model\User)#572 (41) {...},
```

So, `#3` actually works - giving me an array with 182 items inside - albeit with only one filter parameter (`isAdmin`). I need to make use of the two params: `isAdmin` `&&` `language`.

I'm following https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.3/reference/query-builder-api.html to the letter. Oh, and as a sanity check:

`> db.User.find({'isAdmin':true, 'language': 'en_GB'})` works beautifully at the `cli`. So what's the problem with `#1` & `#2`. Any ideas?

Comment: What `$this->getCountry()->getRegion()` returns exactly?  Does it work if you hardcode `en_GB` as a language?

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's returning a string `GB` whereas the actual value in the db is the string `en_GB` hence no results. Thanks Alex.